# Show only the latest 3 results using a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, angularjs

I have a script that pulls in results and displays it on my site. I want to display only the last three results that are being pulled instead of everything. So the latest results are `Test2`, `Test1` and then Office 365 Planned Service.

Here are all the results being pulled:

[image]

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training"
    });

    $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.orderBy("Created", false).get().then(function(items) {
        console.log(items);
        var result = items.map(item => {
            return {
                Title: item.Title,
                Description: item.Description,
                Link: item.Link
            }
        });
        var $table = roadMapDisplay(result);
        console.log($table);
        $('#title').html($table);
    });

    function roadMapDisplay(items) {

        var table = $('<container/>');

        items.forEach(item => {
            table.append(`<a href="${item.Link}" target="_blank" style="font-size: larger;">${item.Title}</a>`);
            table.append(`<div style="text-indent: 10px">${item.Description.slice(0, -200)}...</div>`);
            table.append('<br/>');
        });
        return table;
    }
});
```

How could I throw a loop onto that function? I've tried so many different ways and have come short.

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Stack Snippets are for **runnable** examples. Clicking Run in your example yields an error. Please edit the snippet so it's runnable and demonstrates the problem, or just use code blocks.

Comment: Sorry Crowder, it won't be able to run because it's using a internal sharepoint list to populate the data and it's restricted. I'm just looking at throwing a loop where the function roadMapDisplay is being run 3 times.

Comment: You can easily mock that up using `setTimeout` and static data.

Comment: `roadMapDisplay` builds a table with all the results. You don't want to call it three times, surely; you just want to call it once with three items...?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, so a Microsoft Flow is setup to grab the latest data from a list. It's got 4 rows in that list now which it's displaying. I want to be able to display only the latest 3.

Comment: i think you can see my example of pnp js. this will work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your are looking for this. if our query always returns top three items then why we explicitly goes to javascript?

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("O365RoadMap").items.top(3).orderBy("Created", false).get().then(function(items) {
console.log(items);
});
```

you can get more knowledge from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items)

Comment: Thanks for this Negi! I'm not too familiar with PnP, so I'm writing this down in my notes.

Comment: its ok dude... if you need further help then you can ask me @SaintLouisEvents

Comment: Perhaps a link to the docs describing this use of `top` would be useful. :-)

Comment: i used in my project so i remembered it @T.J.Crowder :)

Comment: Unclear how that addresses the suggestion to link documentation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , it means i used this code in my project but currently i don't remember the source.

Answer (score 1):

The following is specific to arrays. However, it appears there's a [`$pnp`-specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520801/157247) which it seems to me should be more efficient.

---

Assuming your current code works (showing the full list), you can grab just the *first* three entries in `items` like this:

```
items = items.slice(0, 3);
```

...or the *last* three like this:

```
items = items.slice(-3);
```

Comment: Let me try this!

Comment: I've tried this, haven't come successful on just displaying the latest three, it still shows up as 4 items. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: There is no way there is a bug in the "slice" function. You did something else there. Add your new code to the question so we can see.

Comment: Got it working, `items.slice(0, 3).forEach(item => {` - The above code didn't work by Crowder but including it before the forEach loop worked perfectly. Thanks for the heads up Crowder!

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents - "The above code didn't work..." Well, that depends on where you used it, but it was only ever meant to be *indicative*, not a copy-and-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

To keep two arrays:

```js
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
var n = 3
var remainingArray = items.splice(0, items.length-n);

console.log(remainingArray)//<--first n elements
 
console.log(items)//<--last n elements
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Emeeus! I got the answer but I will keep this in my notes for future instances that I need.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that $pnp is the PnP JavaScript Library With jQuery In SharePoint based on a quick search online.

I don't know too much about PnP; however, I noticed this documentation in https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items:

> // use odata operators for more efficient queries
>
> $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.select("Title", "Description").top(5).orderBy("Modified", true).get().then((items: any[]) => {
>       console.log(items);
>   });

As you can see they are using "top(5)"; therefore, you could change the order, so you get first the last elements, then use top(3) to obtain those three records you wish to display.

Since $pnp seems to follow a chain pattern, I wonder if you could apply again the order method after obtaining the top(3).

Comment: This should be an edit to [the existing `$php` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51520801/157247).

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @carlstein! Negi did mention the top() attribute in PnP which does exactly what it is needed to do.